# Domino spawner and rotator

Tags: roblox

the problem i got was this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEB2j.png)
I am a begginer at lua, so the code may not be optimized.

```
local click
local a

local spawner = Instance.new("Part",workspace)
spawner.Name = "spawner"
spawner.Position = Vector3.new(22, 0.125, 30)
spawner.Size = Vector3.new(4, 0.25, 4)
spawner.Anchored = true
Instance.new("ClickDetector",workspace.spawner)
click = game.Workspace.spawner.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    local domino = Instance.new("Part",game.Workspace.dominos)
    domino.Orientation = Vector3.new(0, -90, -90)
    domino.Size = Vector3.new(8,2,4)
    domino.Position = Vector3.new(40, 6, 30)
    domino.Color = Color3.new(1,0,0)
    Instance.new("ClickDetector",workspace.dominos.Part)
    domino.Name = "domino"
a = game.Workspace.dominos.domino.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
a.Orientation = Vector3.new(0,-90,-90)
    end)
end)
```

I was making a local script in Lua that lets you spawn blocks like dominoes and rotate them to make them stand up.

Comment: You should probably mention what the host environment for this script is.

Comment: Please set the corresponding tag (roblox?)